# Did I use "as a ..." correctly?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

I am writing to a Biology professor and would like to know if the "As a...," is used correctly.

> As an instructor of Cell Biology, I wanted you to know that the library has free video resources.

To me, it seems like I am the instructor of Cell Biology rather than the person reading the message.

Comment: "As you are an instructor..."

Answer (score -2):

You are correct. As the sentence is currently written, it's an example of a [**misplaced modifier**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier):

> A **misplaced modifier** is a type of ambiguous grammatical construct whereby a grammatical modifier could be misinterpreted as being associated with a word other than the one intended. A **dangling modifier** is one that has no subject at all. For example, a writer may have meant to modify the subject, but word order used means that the modifier appears to modify an object instead. Such ambiguities can lead to unintentional humor, or, in formal contexts, difficulty in comprehension.
>
> Take, for example, the sentence *Turning the corner, a handsome school building appeared.* The modifying clause *Turning the corner* is clearly supposed to describe the behavior of the narrator (or other observer), but grammatically it appears to apply either to nothing in particular, or to the "handsome school building".

In the case of your sentence, you don't have a *dangling modifier*, because the sentence has a clear subject (*I*); however, the modifying clause *As an instructor of Cell Biology* is modifying the wrong subject (*I* rather than the instructor).

---

To correct it, you need to make the subject of the modifying clause explicit:

> As **you are** an instructor of Cell Biology, I wanted you to know that the library has free video resources.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you for the clear explanation.